# What service can I use to send a test email every day?

Tags: email, cloud-service

I run a mail server and I want to send an email every day to a test inbox.

The email doesn't need any dynamic behaviour, it can be completely static (subject, content, target inbox, etc.) , I just want to send it ever day at the same time.

Is there any kind of "as a service" type product out there that can do this (I know there's loads of ways I could do this if I wanted to build something myself, but I don't want to do that right now).

That's all I'm looking to do:

- sign up to the service
- create a test email with a subject, content and target inbox
- set it to send every day

Comment: I assume the test shall run from a machine other than the mail server, to test if the mail server is still working correctly? If so, don't you have some other Linux machine available where you could set up a Cron job? The `mail` command then could do what you asked for. Alternatively, just subscribe to some daily newsletter #D

Answer (score 1):

[IFTTT](https://ifttt.com) (If This Then That) provides a way to do this.  After you register, you can add an applet using the '+' icon at the top of the screen on you mobile device. Select the 'this' keyword followed by the 'date & time' service.  Once that loads, select the 'Every day at' option.  You will be prompted for the time you want the email to fire. Once that is set, select the check mark.  This sends you back to the new applet setup but this time the 'that' option is highlighted.  Select it.  There are many options.  Thus far, I have not been able to make this step work however.

Answer (score 1):

Try sending a message from the test address to `every1am@followupthen.com`. FollowUpThen will then send it a message each day at 1 AM. [Documentation is here.](https://www.followupthen.com/how)